# How to Import shape file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, import, spatial, shapefile

I need to import the spatial data in shape file into MySQL tables. I am able to import into PostGreSQL. Any pointers for MySQL. I need the data in MySQL table.

Comment: I am looking what exactly I need to do ?
Do I need to install things extra tools something FWtools 
I do have SQL2008R2 installed, what else I need ?

Answer (score 11):

try this with FWtool installed

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:database_name,host=localhost,user=root,password=1234 C:\route_path\line.shp -nln datatable_name -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

try install for a better result in any process Osgeo4w

http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: I tried that as well, but It didn't work because of some error regarding driver not found.

Comment: but the error will comes with FWTools or Osgeo4w, you could place the code you used

Comment: The Ogre works wonders!  You have to have the .shx file in the same dir as the .shp for it to work, and if you want any data to correspond with your shapes, you will need the .dbf files there as well, however it does not throw an error if it is not there: you will just end up with shapes with indexes (pretty useless to me).

Comment: OSGeo4W is only for Windows, and I need to do this on linux. Do you know if there are any linux tools available that do this too?

Comment: OSGeo4W is a packpage compiled for windows, the source is GDAL, GRASS, etc, find this in the documentation of de osgeo4w

Answer (score 1):

I have just used the ogr2ogr command line tool to import the shape file into the mysql database. Make sure that the database server allows external connections. If doesn't, then it throws all sorts of errors.

Once you have that you can use -

Select ASTEXT(Shape) POLYGON from world to get an array of the polygon coordinates etc