# shp2mysql: Shapefile import to mysql

Tags: mysql, shapefile

I want to import [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) to mysql database with `shp2mysql` tool:

> shp2mysql roads1 roads_table my_db > roads.sql

But I get this error:

> Can't locate Geo/Shapelib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/bin/shp2mysql line 9.

I can't figure out why, please help. Thanks.

PS: I'm working on ubuntu 12.04 Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install this Perl module:

http://search.cpan.org/~ajolma/Geo-Shapelib-0.20/Shapelib.pm

I'm not expert in Perl, but you can try use the command `cpan`. I followed the default steps to configure it (except `What approach do you want?`, when I chose `sudo`, but I'm not sure). Then run the command:

`install Geo::Shapelib`

Good luck

PS: Another tool that you may try is ogr2ogr. It worked for me. See this thread:

[How to Import shape file into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123765/how-to-import-shape-file-into-mysql)